# Where can I see AWS Access Key auto deletion policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-access-policy

In my current work place, AWS Access Keys are deleted after 90 days for human users.
For system users, the key is not deleted and throws an alert that key has gone over 90 days.

In the absence of anyone else at my workplace explaining this to me, I want to understand how this policy could have been implemented within AWS.

Where can I look into our AWS account to learn more about this implementation.
thanks

Answer (score 1):

See [Getting credential reports for your AWS account](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_getting-report.html). There is an underlying IAM API called [GetCredentialReport](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/APIReference/API_GetCredentialReport.html).

> You can generate and download a credential report that lists all users in your account and the status of their various credentials, including passwords, access keys, and MFA devices. You can get a credential report from the AWS Management Console, the AWS SDKs and Command Line Tools, or the IAM API.

One way to call it is via the [awscli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/get-credential-report.html):

```
aws iam get-credential-report
```

Passwords expire based on a [password policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_passwords_account-policy.html). Also see [Managing access keys for IAM users](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_access-keys.html).